# How can I use WP_Query to display selected Category posts from the custom post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using custom post type plugin and I am trying to loop only selected post for a particular category within my custom post. I would like to loop only selected category. Any suggestion?

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$loop=new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'custom post';
    'taxonomy '->'private';
    'sort_column' => 'post_date',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1 ,
    'order' => 'ASC')
); 
if ( $loop->have_posts() ){?>

    <?php 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
    {
        $loop->the_post();
        $meta=get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wp_query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

```
$loop=new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'custom post',
    'taxonomy' =>'private',
    'sort_column' => 'post_date',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'cat' => 19
)
);
```

Comment: Hello Prakash & Gal thanks for the suggestion, 
@prakash regarding your suggestion i  am still working to make a fix but still can't find my solution on this.
And regarding gal , I am not getting the post no error but simply when i add the category_in the post is not showing .
I am trying with :
' <?php
                $loop=new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'journeypackage',
    'taxonomy '=>'journy_category',
    'sort_column' => 'post_date',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1 ,
    'order' => 'ASC',
     'category__in' => array(19)
)
); '

Comment: @lisageni I edited my answer so it would display also a child categories let me know if its working

Comment: @lisageni you had few issues within your array like `;` instead of `,` and `->` instead of `=>` also haven't seen in the docs the argument `taxonomy` (at least not the way your using it) what is it suppose to stands for ?display to logged in users ? if so you may want to use `post_status` argument instead.

Comment: Yes i have fixed those issue , But the thing is my custom post are working fine , When i try to add this  'category__in' => 19 suddently no post in the custom post is not showing up .

Comment: @lisageni look at my edited post,as I mentioned earlier category__in doesn't display child categories which might be your case.(switch to `cat` argument)

Comment: Hello Gal , i have tried the one what you have updated, But still getting the same : 
Please find the difference in the below screenshot :
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/997447/37dd56e839030bd9db8d5c77c52c1b49
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/997454/f7becf5cca26949343a44900fa9ede5e

Comment: @lisageni are you sure that the category is 19 ? could you change the argument to `category__not_in` and set the value to 19 and see what happen ? also please post the updated arguments array and check that debug mode is on maybe you get some error on the query builder and that's why it doesn't display any result.

Comment: @ Gal category__not_in is showing all the post in the custom post .  I have created the custom post type taxanomy as catagory_private and my catagory's are private_only and public . private_only cat id is 19 and i have selected the tag in my post but still not working .  Even i am getting the same with atif tariq code suggestion .

Comment: @lisageni couldn't really understand what you mean by ' showing all the post in the custom post' ,if it gives you the same result as without `category__not_in` then it means that 19 isn't the category your looking for. please update the question with the arguments you sent and the results you got.

Answer (score 0):

Use tax query of wordpress inside the wp_query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'custom post';
    'posts_per_page'=> -1 ,
    'order' => 'ASC'
    'orderby' => 'ID'

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'private',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and replace the `'terms'    => 'bob',` with `'terms'    => '<your category slug>',` Slug can be checked from back-end

Answer (score 0):

use it like this:

```
<?php
$loop=new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'custom post';
    'posts_per_page'=> -1 ,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'ID',

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'private',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob'
        ),
    ),
);
); 
if ( $loop->have_posts() ){?>

    <?php 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
    {
        $loop->the_post();
        $meta=get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'');

?>
```